# Eyeball sticking out of mesh when blinking

Tags: mesh

[image]
My eyeball is sticking out of my mesh when blinking. How do I fix this?

Comment: move the eye back or the eyelid forward.

Comment: If I move vertices of the eyelid in edit mode will it interfere with the rig or weight paint?